# Magento 2: Cacheable false for specific block not working

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I am trying to detect user’s country based on their IP address and ability to change country as well. However with the use of Full Page Cache, country name is not getting display properly. Sometimes it displays random results.

I have tried to add **cacheable=false** to block XML file. But adding this would slow down entire page. Since this block is added to all pages, entire site getting slow by adding **cacheable=false.**

Also tried **`_isScopeprivate = true`** to my block PHP **`__construct()`** function. But this is also not working.

**Is there any way to exclude specific block from FPC without hurting site speed?**

I have rewrite currency.phtml template for customize my goal,

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Currency" name="currency" template="Vendor_Module::currency.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**when i am keep cacheable=false in above block its working but page load time take so much time.**
So I want to remove **cacheable="false"** from above block.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Good question, How are you redirecting and fetching country based on Ip. Could you please elaborate your exact problem

Comment: @Rakesh did you get some solution for this?

Comment: @Rakesh and Mohammad I am facing same issue in Magento 2.1.10 . Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @rakesh, Did you get any solution?

Comment: @PushpendraSingh had you found any solution for this?

Comment: @MuditGulgulia, you can use js for this, load content according to your requirement

Answer (score 5):

`cacheable=false` on a block makes whole page not cacheable. This is how it is designed, so no problem here.

As for your goal - you want to render user-specific content as part of cached page. Such content should not be rendered on server. It should be retrieved from server using customer data JS api (see mini shopping cart), and rendered using JS.

Alternatively you can redirect user to proper country page based and not care about it on magento side.

Comment: thanks for your reply, please check my updated questions.

Comment: when enable cacheable=false in currency block, page load time is doubled. so i want to find new solutions using cacheble=true. so page load time getting fast.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Did you find any solution for this. I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

try to extend `Vendor\Module\Block\Currency` and add:

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

to this class.

Comment: this solution is not working in magento 2.4.5