# What is the difference b/w cacheable="false" and Sections in Magento 2

Tags: cache, section

I have developed an extension in magento 2.2.6. Now i am upgrade this in magento 2.3.1 but I am facing 1 issue.

In my phtml file **$block->method()** is called 1 time after cache:clean.

When I refresh the page second time then   **$block->method()**  execution does not reach in method body. I have done testing by writing `die();` in method body and also return preview loaded data.

And now I am write cacheable="false" for block in layout file, then it works like 2.2.6. i.e on every refresh $block->method() read execution in method body.

I don't understand why need cache:clean on every refresh if don't use cacheable="false" .

And what is the best practice for this? May I use cacheable="false" or section.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cacheable="false"` means you have made **your block cache lifetime 0**  means the cache is not generated for that Block. That is very bad for site speed Up.

**Most importance disadvantage** of `cacheable="false"` is that If you make any block of a page `cacheable="false"` that means that Page fully Non-cachable

See that Magento Main architect **Anton Kril** post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134444/4564

*That why Magento Custom account pages/Checkout/Cart Page is not cacheable.*

Where, `section.xml` is a different concept using this private content of specific to individual users, it’s reasonable to handle it on the client (i.e., web browser).

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html